Projection in a hereditary subalgebra of a purely infinite C*-algebra
Let $A$ be a simple non-zero purely infinite C*-algebra. Let $p\in A$ be a projection. Then $E=pAp$ is a hereditary subalgebra. Since $A$ is purely infinite, $E$ has an infinite projection $q$.
Q. Is $q\leq p$? If so, why?
Definitions:

A simple C-algebra is purely infinite if every hereditary C-subalgebra contains an infinite projection.


An projection is infinite if it is Murray-vN equivalent to a proper subprojection of itself.


Since $q\in pAp$, we have $q=pqp\le |q|p^2=p$.

@Aweygan 1. $q$ just need be equal to $pap$ for some $a\in A$. Why should $a=q$? 2. $||q||^2=||q||p$. But then $||q||$ is less than 1 since it is a projection. so we dont get the last equality.

Since $q\in pAp$, you have that $q=pqp$: if $q=pap$, then
$$
pqp=p(pap)p=pap=q. 
$$
Then, since $q\leq1$,
$$
q=pqp\leq p1p=p^2=p. 
$$

Thank you for your answer. My C*-algebra need not be unital though

Ok, but $q\leq p$ on $A$ if and only if $q\leq p$ on the unitization of $A$.
